# Template function for max_element on maps needs to know both types

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I'm trying to write a custom cmp function for a map, a simple one that does the comparison over the second element of the map. I'd like to have the function as a template, but I can't figure out how to pass the map's `.first` and `.second` types along to my cmp function. My non-working code is below, which will clearly fail since the type of T1 and T2 are not passed along:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<class T1, class T2>
bool pairCompare(const std::pair<T1,T2> & x,
                 const std::pair<T1,T2> & y) {
  return x.second < y.second; 
}

template<class T1>
typename T1::iterator map_max_element(const T1 & A) {

  // How do I pass the type to pairCompare?
  return std::max_element(A.begin(), A.end(), pairCompare<?????>);
}

int main() {
  std::map<std::vector<double>, int> A;
  map_max_element(A);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure to use `std::vector<double>` as key type for your map? `std::map<int, std::vector<double> >`  makes more sense, imho.

Comment: @constantinius Usually I'd agree with you, but for this particular case I'm mapping a known set of discrete set points in R^n to a set of integers to what will essentially be a lookup table for those points. The particulars of this map are irrelevant for the question however.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`std::map` has a nested type called `value_type` which is actually a typedef of `std::pair<const K, V>`. And `std::pair` has two nested types `first_type` and `second_type`.  Use this info as:

```
template<class T>
typename T::const_iterator map_max_element(const T & A) 
{
   typedef typename T::value_type pair_type;
   typedef typename pair_type::first_type K;
   typedef typename pair_type::second_type V;
   return std::max_element(A.begin(), A.end(), pairCompare<K,V>);
}
```

Note that in your code the return type is wrong. It should be `const_iterator`, rather than `iterator`, because in the function `A` is const map. Hence what you can get from it is `const_iterator`. :-)

---

Or you could simply write the compare function as:

```
template<class T>
bool pairCompare(const T & x, const T & y) {
  return x.second < y.second; 
}
```

And use it as:

```
return std::max_element(A.begin(), A.end(), pairCompare<typename T::value_type>);
```

Comment: Both results in `error: conversion from 'std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::vector<double>, int> >' to non-scalar type 'std::map<std::vector<double>, int>::iterator' requested`

Comment: @Frigo: Its because of the return type, in OP code, which I copied. It should be `const_iterator`, rather than `iterator`. And the second one now will compile; it was missing the template argument.

Comment: Yup, got it working. Edit your answer to reflect these and gonna vote you up.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `T1::key_type` and `T1::mapped_type`, or more simply, just `T1::value_type`, which is equivalent to `std::pair<T1::key_type,T1::mapped_type>`.

Comment: You've to use `typename` also, as in `typename T1::key_type`.

Answer (score 2):

Having the same question as the poster. I tried the answer proposed. Works fine with some little modifications.

Thats the final code that works with a little example to test.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
bool pairCompare(const T & x, const T & y)
{
  return x.second < y.second;
}

template<class T>
typename T::const_iterator map_max_element(const T &A)
{
    typedef typename T::value_type pair_type;
    return max_element(A.begin(), A.end(), pairCompare<typename T::value_type>);
}

int main()
{
    map<float, int> A;
    map<float, int>::const_iterator it;
    // Data insert

    A.insert ( pair<float, int>( -2, 1) );
    A.insert ( pair<float, int>( 0, 5) );
    A.insert ( pair<float, int>( 2, -5) );

    it = map_max_element(A);

    cout << "Row with maximum second element of a Map: " << (*it).first << " , " << (*it).second << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Enjoy the code and thanks for this great work Nawan.